# Can a virtual image create another image?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Can a virtual image created by a concave lens create any image by the convex lens oriented parallel (at the same direction of refracted rays of the concave one) with the concave one? If not, can any other orientation of the convex lens can do the work? What is the effectiveness of a high powered convex lens to do the stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual image and a real image of an object are not very different.  They both consist of rays of light that appear to come from an "new" object located somewhere in space.  The difference is that for a virtual image, the light doesn't actually come from that "new" object. But some other optical element doesn't "know" where the light has been, only how it is behaving at the moment that it hits the new optical element.

For example, the virtual image created by a plane mirror is located behind the mirror.  The light never goes there, but your eye, a telescope, a camera all act as if the light does.  If you're taking a selfie standing 3 metres from a mirror, you focus your camera at 6 metres.

Consider a very near-sighted person.  They will wear concave glasses that create a near-by virtual image of a distant object, so that the lens in the eye can create a real, in-focus image on the person's retina...